# Why is information not doubled in this context?

Tags: information

Regarding the following section from a text:

[image]

Why is information not doubled but increased 4/3 times? Can you give an example to clarify what is meant here?

What is meant by information here?

Comment: Hard to see what the original idea was as the context is clipped out, but the numbers are there. Increasing by one bit from 3 to 4, that is really just 1.33 times more information in bits.

Comment: that clipping js incomplete ... you are asking a question without presenting all of the information

Comment: i think that you are confusing the number of available combinations ... that would double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I roll an eight-sided die, then I could represent the result with three bits.

If I roll **two** eight-sided dice, I have generated double the information -- and I need six bits (three bits for each die) to represent that information.

If I have just four bits, I could represent the result of rolling a 16-sided die, or the result of rolling an 8-sided die and flipping a coin -- but I could not represent the result of rolling two dice.

This is why information theory represents a basic unit of information as a bit -- because it fits with our intuitive understanding of what "X times more information" is.  Twice as many books is twice as much information (presumably), two phone conversations is twice as much information, etc.  Twice as many books, or twice as many phone conversations, takes twice as many bits to represent.  Hence information theorists equate one binary bit with one "bit" of information.

Comment: If we have 16 books and make it 64 books the number of bits needed increases 1.5 times but the number of books increases 4 times. I don’t understand what you mean by relating number of books to bits in your example.

Comment: When I say "represent" I mean "to print out", i.e. the size of the PDF file you need to contain the book.  If a book takes \$N\$ bits to represent and you have 16 unique books, then you need \$16N\$ bits to represent those 16 books.  If you increase the size of your library to 64 unique book, then you need \$64N\$ bits to represent those books.  \$64 / 16 = 4\$, not 1.5.  You are probably thinking of the number of bits you'd need to **count** the books -- that's different.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way. The universe of states that could be coded by 3 bits vs. 4 bits doubles from 8 to 16. But the *information* contained in those 8 or 16 states can be optimally represented with 3 or 4 bits.

That is, you have 8 or 16 *symbols*, which can be optimally coded with 3 or 4 bits. The relationship of symbols to bits is as follows:

- Number of bits of information >= log(base2) (Number of symbols)

More here: https://plus.maths.org/content/information-birth-bit

In your example then, the *information* is only increased by 1 bit from 3 to 4, so the ratio is 4/3.